# ДКА. Принадлежность последовательности автомату

Tags: python, алгоритм, конечные-автоматы

У меня было задание для конкретного автомата проверить -- принадлежит ли ему выражение (можно ли по этому выражению придти в конечное состояние автомата).

Для автомата на картинке проверка следующая :

```
def accept(begin_state, final, strr): 
    for i in strr:

        if begin_state == 2:
            if i == 'a':
                begin_state = 0
                continue

        elif begin_state == 0:
            if i == 'a':
                begin_state = 1
                continue

        elif begin_state == 1:
            if i == 'a':
                begin_state = 2
            if i == 'b':
                begin_state = 3
            if i == 'c':
                begin_state = 4
                continue

        elif begin_state == 3:
            if i == 'b':
                begin_state = 3
            if i == 'c':
                begin_state = 5
                continue

    if begin_state in final:
        print ("Correct")
        return True
    else:
        print("NOT Correct")

    return False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    begin_state = 0
    end_stare = False
    final = [4, 5]
    strr = input("Enter stuff: ")
    strr.replace(' ', '')
    strr = list(strr)
    accept(begin_state, final, strr)
```

**Вопрос**: как можно реализовать общий случай проверки принадлежности выражения? я думаю, можно хранить состояния в виде списка списков, но как проверять дальше?

[image: Частный автомат]

Comment: Есть решение задачи проверки принадлежности цепочки автомату, когда автомат задан таблично. Если интересует - могу скинуть в ответ. Для использования нужно будет перевести автомат из представления в виде графа к представлению в виде таблицы переходов

Comment: @Евгений, для сравнения, если Вам не трудно)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вариант решения задачи распознавания цепочки для автомата, представленного таблично:

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals

"""
* Входные данные для проверки
"""

# Автомат в табличном виде
f = """
   a  b  c
0  1  3  E  0
1  2  E  E  0
2  0  E  E  0
3  E  5  4  0
4  E  E  E  1
5  E  E  E  1
E  E  E  E  0
"""

# Проверяемая цепочка
chain = 'aaabc'
# chain = input() # раскомментировать, если цепочку нужно вводить с клавиатуры


"""
* Работа алгоритма
"""

f = [line for line in f.split('\n') if line.strip()]

alphabet = [
    letter.strip()
    for letter in f[0].split()
    if letter.strip()
]

if len(alphabet) != len(set(alphabet)):
    raise Exception("В алфавите недопустимы повторяющиеся символы")

alphabet = {
    alphabet[i] : i
    for i in range(len(alphabet))
}

constructor = {
    f[i].split()[0] : (f[i].split()[1:-1], f[i].split()[-1])
    for i in range(1, len(f))
}

status = list(constructor.keys())[0]
for c in chain:
    status = constructor[status][0][alphabet[c]]
    print(f'Символ: {c}; Статус: {status}')
print(f'Результат: цепочка {"принимается" if int(constructor[status][1]) else "отвергается"}')
```

Как уже было сказано в другом ответе, представленный вами граф не является корректным автоматом, потому в примере приведены следующие изменения:

- Убрана цепочка `3 -b-> 3`
- Состояния `4` и `5` выделены как принимающие
- Добавлено `E`-состояние для переходов, которых нет на графе
- Состояние `0` выделено как начальное (по умолчанию начальным состоянием считается первая строка табличного автомата)

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в автомате ошибка, как минимум одна, но скорее всего 4 (либо Вы используете специфическую нотацию для ДКА). Т.е. у Вас не [ДКА](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82). В частности, он НЕ детерминированный. Цитата:

> Детерминированным конечным автоматом (ДКА) называется такой автомат, в
>   котором нет дуг с меткой ε (предложение, не содержащее ни одного
>   символа), и из любого состояния по любому символу возможен переход не
>   более, чем в одно состояние.

*В вершине 3 у вас есть 2 ребра с одинаковыми символами для перехода. Далее, я буду считать, что петля для символа 3 имеет символ **d**, а не **b**.*

*Также у Вас не выбраны единственные: начальная и конечная вершины. Я выберу их сам: 0 и 5 соответсвенно.*

*Для вершины 4, если считать её не конечной нет перехода.*. Но мы на это забъём.

*В начальную вершину не может быть ребёр*. Не обращаем внимания.

Всё очень несложно. Задача формулируется так. Дан граф **G = G(V, E)**, где **V** -- множество вершин с двумя выделенными вершинами: начальная и конечная (минимальный *id*, максимальный *id*). **E** -- множество пар **(vi, vj)**, где **vi, vj** -- вершины. Требуется построить алгоритм, который по упорядоченному списку вершин даст ответ: существует ли такой путь в графе или нет.

Пример. Пусть есть тот граф, который Вы предложили. Начальное состояние: 0, конечное состояние: 1. Зададим путь: [a,a,a,a,a,a,b,d,b]. Тогда: 0-1-2-0-1-2-0-3-3-5

Другой пример: [a,a,a,a,a,a,b,c,c]. Здесь получается, что мы оказываемся не в финальной вершине.

Модификация [алгоритма обхода в глубину](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) решает Вашу задачу. Граф будем [хранить](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) как матрицу смежности, представленную словарём вершин и их соседей.

```
def iterate_over_neighbours(elem, ngbs):
    next_vertex = None
    for label, vertex in ngbs.items():
        if elem != label:
            continue
        next_vertex = vertex
        break
    if next_vertex is None:
        return -1
    return next_vertex


def dfs(g, seq, s, f):
    cv = s  # current vertex
    step = 0
    for step in range(len(seq)):
        if cv == f:
            break
        next_vertex = iterate_over_neighbours(seq[step], g[cv])
        if next_vertex == -1:
            return False
        cv = next_vertex
    if cv == f and len(seq)-1 == step:
        return True
    return False


g = {
   0: {'a': 1, 'b': 3},
   1: {'a': 2},
   2: {'a': 0},
   3: {'d': 3, 'c': 4, 'b': 5},
   4: {},
   5: {},
}
final = 5
start = 0
seq = ['a','a','a','a','a','a','b','d','b']
print(dfs(g, seq, start, final))
```

Comment: Вау, это отличная идея. Спасибо Вам большое

Comment: @Annya тогда Вы можете отметить ответ как верный (=

Comment: @hedgehogues мне кажется, вот это будет тоже самое делать `def dfs(g, seq, cv, f):
    for i in seq:
        try:
            cv = g[cv][i]
        except:
            return False
    return cv == f  `

Comment: @splash58 хз, может быть. Вероятно, есть корнер-кейсы.

Comment: Я исключительно про стиль кода )

Comment: @splash58 да, у Вас значительно короче, если это работает (=

Comment: @splash58 что со стилем кода?

Comment: @hedgehogues, разбираюсь в вашем коде: подскажите пожалуйста , функция iterate_over_neighbours просто определяет, если ли следующая непройденная вершина в графе?(потому что не совсем ясно, что такое l и v )Спасибо

Comment: @Annya фактически, да. Т.е. подбираем следующую вершиу. l -- label. v -- vertex